# querySelectorAll throws DOM Exception when selector contains forward slash

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit

Possibly a daft question, but I'm having trouble with document.querySelectorAll().

I'm trying to find a tag with a mime-type as it's property. For example

```
document.querySelectorAll('style[type=text/css]');
```

On Chrome 9, this throws the following error

```
Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
```

If I omit the type attribute, it does not throw an error. If I remove the forward slash it also does not throw an error (but obviously does not return any nodes).

I know there are simple work arounds getting all elements, and testing each one for it's type property, but I curious why this isn't working. Do I need to escape the forward slash? Or perhaps is this simply not a supported selector in Chrome 9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried

```
document.querySelectorAll('style[type="text/css"]');
```